# Get column index by name in QgsAttributeTableModel

Tags: pyqgis

In a QSqlTabelModel I can get the index of a column like this:

```
my_table_model.fieldIndex('column_name')
```

How can I do the same with a QgsAttributeTableModel? I have tried .fieldCol and .fieldIdx, but both are returning an index by a given index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need more context for that. For example, I'm going to show up the attributes table of following vector layer by using 'show' method of **QgsAttributeTableView** class; where it is also necessary to use **QgsAttributeTableModel** class.

[image]

Complete code is exposed below:

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayerCache
from qgis.gui import QgsAttributeTableModel, QgsAttributeTableView, QgsAttributeTableFilterModel

layer = iface.activeLayer()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, 10000)
attribute_table_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(vector_layer_cache)
attribute_table_model.loadLayer()

attribute_table_filter_model = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(canvas,
                                                            attribute_table_model)

attribute_table_view = QgsAttributeTableView()
attribute_table_view.setBaseSize(800,100)
attribute_table_view.setModel(attribute_table_filter_model)

attribute_table_view.show()
```

After running it at Python Console of QGIS, attributes table appears as it is showed at below image:

[image]

It can be observed different fields for its attributes table. As **QgsAttributeTableModel** class has 'layer' method for producing a **QgsVectorLayer** object, it is easy to connect it with 'indexFromName' method from **QgsFields** class for returning index, e.g., for 'area' field:

```
>>>attribute_table_model.layer().fields().indexFromName('area')
5
```

where result (index 5) is as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, i will check it out in a few days.

Comment: You are right, it works perfect!